# CanActivate Promise<boolean> does not navigatebyurl after reject

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication

Finally got CanActivate when trying to divert different users by their roles to different areas of the app. However, if they go to the wrong route, I can't get this to redirect. Here's what I have:

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {

            if (user) {
                let userProfile = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}`);
                userProfile.once("value", (snapshot) => {
                    let userInfo = snapshot.val().role;
                    if (userInfo === "GroupA") {
                        resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        reject(this.router.navigate(['/login']));
                    }
                });

            } else {
                reject(this.router.navigate(['/login']));
            }

        });

    });
}
```

Why won't it router.navigate? 100% open to hearing about better ideas to do this.

Comment: By wrong route what do you mean ? means a route which is not defined . you can make use of wild character ** in your routing file to redirec if he goes to a wrong route

Comment: Both routes are defined. /GroupA and /GroupB but neither one can go to either users routes. So, ** would see those both as valid routes.

Answer (score 2):

The `CanActivate` return promise expects only to be *resolved*, to either `true` or `false`, and will throw an error if you *reject* it.

This should work:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    let navigateToLogin = () => this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
            if (user.isAuthenticated) {
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                navigateToLogin();
                resolve(false);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works!

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {

            if (user) {
                let userProfile = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}`);
                userProfile.once("value", (snapshot) => {
                    let userInfo = snapshot.val().role;
                    if (userInfo === "provider") {
                        resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        reject(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }).catch(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    });

    return promise.then(() => {
        return true;
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
 }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work